# Is there a way to convert wildcard imports in java source code to named imports based on the code?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, wildcard, java-11

I am trying to sort through a lot of Java code and see exactly what the imports are. I am looking for a script, or some functionality from an IDE that would replace wildcard import statements with named import statements. So this:

```
import java.io.*; //Wildcard import

public class hello {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File myObj = new File("hello.txt"); 
    System.out.println(myObj); 
  }
}
```

Would become this:

```
import java.io.File; //Named import

public class hello {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File myObj = new File("hello.txt"); 
    System.out.println(myObj); 
  }
}
```

Based on 'File', from java.io appearing in the code. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes. Use eclipse. [Organize imports](https://dzone.com/articles/organize-imports-eclipse). Done.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in Eclipse there are two steps.

First, you want to change your "organize imports" preferences, so that a large number of individual imports are never replaced with an asterisk.  I do that by changing both the numeric fields under **Window | Preferences | Java | Code Style | Organize Imports** to an impossibly large number, as shown here.

[image]

Once you've done that, the **Source | Organize Imports** option (also available as Ctrl+Shift+O) will arrange your `import` statements in order, and replace any asterisks with the full names of every class that's being imported.

Comment: Works perfectly thank you!